# Jquery Show div with matching class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a `div` when an item with a class name the same as the hidden `div's` id is clicked.

The problem is when I click it reveals all of them instead of the particular one I'm clicking on.

This is my code so far:

```js
 $("#mixers").on("click", ".clear-tile", function() {
   $("#mixers li").each(function() {
     $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).removeClass('display-hide');
   });
 });
```

```css
.display-hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mixers">
  <li class="one"><span class="clear-tile">Show One</span></li>
  <li class="two"><span class="clear-tile">Show Two</span></li>
  <li class="three"><span class="clear-tile">Show Three</span></li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="display-hide"><p>I'm One</p></div>
<div id="two" class="display-hide"><p>I'm Two</p></div>
<div id="three" class="display-hide"><p>I'm Three</p></div>
```

Comment: `.each()` is looping through all of the `<li>` tags and executing the `.removeClass()` operation for all of the divs. You only want to do this for the parent `$(this).parent().attr('class')`...

Comment: Seirously why the downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Dont iterate over them with `each`, that will show them all
2. Use `parent()` to traverse up to the `li` with the class identifier

```js
$("#mixers").on("click", ".clear-tile", function() {
  $('#' + $(this).parent('li').attr('class')).removeClass('display-hide');
});
```

```css
.display-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mixers">
  <li class="one"><span class="clear-tile">Show One</span>
  </li>
  <li class="two"><span class="clear-tile">Show Two</span>
  </li>
  <li class="three"><span class="clear-tile">Show Three</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="display-hide">
  <p>I'm One</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="display-hide">
  <p>I'm Two</p>
</div>
<div id="three" class="display-hide">
  <p>I'm Three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually doesnt work for my implementation it works fine here but doesn't work and actually now it doesn't reveal anything at all. Im also confused about the use of .parent what is it's purpose?

Comment: @DCdaz, this was a straight copy-paste of the code in your question. Can you give me a live site or fiddle where its not working so I can be able to better help you?

Comment: Hi Ammar your edit actually works the previous one you had up didnt awwarding you the tick

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$("#mixers").on("click", ".clear-tile", function() {
   $('#' + $(this).parent().attr('class'))
        .toggleClass('display-hide')
           .siblings('div')
             .addClass('display-hide');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5a0jzxc7/)**